# Multidimensional $_SESSION array to NULL

Tags: php, session, php-7

**Running PHP 7.x**

I'm using some $_SESSION arrays in this fashion:

```
$_SESSION['form_data']['form_field'] = $data;
```

There are multiple 'form_field' for each 'form_data'.

This $_SESSION is only set if the form data has been changed.
How can I set the $_SESSION to NULL if it is empty, without having to go thru each one separately?

I've tried $_SESSION['form_data'] = NULL;
But, that doesn't seem to work.
If $_SESSION['form_data']['form_field'] is on the page without being specifically set, it throws an warning.

I know I can hide the warnings without issue, but I'd rather figure out the correct way to do this.  Or, is hiding the warning the correct way?

Thanks,
Rick

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
EDITED TO ADD ADD'L CODE
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
//Displays original data from database unless new data was submitted in form
function display_form_value($orig_data = NULL, $new_data = NULL) {
    if(trim($new_data) != NULL) {
        return $new_data;
    } else {
        return $orig_data;
    }
 }
```

On my form Processing Page:

```
$defineTopLink = $_POST['defineTopLinkFollow_1']; //Add'l security removed for clarity
if($defineTopLink != $define['TopLink']) { 
    //$define['TopLink'] is a value pulled from the database
    $_SESSION['form_data']['defineTopLink'] = $defineTopLink; }
    else { 
        $_SESSION['form_data']['defineTopLink'] = "";
    }
```

On the Form Page

```
<input 
    id="defineTopLink_1" 
    name="defineTopLink_1" 
    type="text" 
    value="<?= display_form_value($define['TopLink'], $_SESSION['form_data']['defineTopLink']) ?>" />
```

Comment: Can you clarify/give some examples? Hard to grasp what you're asking.

Comment: Example code added to original question

Answer (score 0):

Hiding warnings or errors is not a good practice. What you might need to do is probably use an `if(isset($_SESSION['form_data']['form_field']))` before actually accessing it.

Even though your description of the fields are not exactly clear, If you do something like below, you would get what you wanted

```
function getFormField($formData, $formField){
  if(isset($_SESSION[$formData][$formField]) {
    return $_SESSION[$formData][$formField];
  }
}

...
//somewhere else in your code

$formData = 'some_form_data';
$formField = 'some_field_name'

$formFieldValue = getFormField(formData,formField)
```

Comment: `$formFieldValue = $_SESSION[$formData][$formField] ?? null;` should be exactly equivalent. I'm not sure that's what OP is asking though.

Comment: @Jeto `??` is a ternary that is php 7+ exclusive; that should be noted when suggesting that. Others may not know what that is.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I mean PHP 7 got released in 2015 and everything below 7.2 has been EOL'd. I don't believe SO answers should assume people are using long-time deprecated versions of a language unless they mention it. Guess that's debatable though. Edit: 2015 not 2005 :)

Comment: @Jeto Oh for sure :) Yet... there are still some that are running under PHP 7. That version probably won't be a new norm for a while though.

Comment: I'm new to Ternary Logic. This seems to be working. Is this the correct way to use it?  display_form_value($define['defineTopLink'], ($_SESSION['form_data']['defineTopLink'] ?: null ))